# how to remove padding for a certain element inside a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some nested columns in my bootstrap design. The grey background color for my  element, has some gaps on the left and right which comes from the padding of bootstrap columns. I can remove the padding by doing `padding:0px` but it will remove padding for all the elements. Is there a way to remove padding for `h3` only?

```
 <div class="col-12">
       <h3 style="text-align:center;background-color:grey;">WAIVER</h3>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
         <p>lorem ipsum</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
         <p>lorem ipsum</p>
       </div
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put inside your h3 style the property padding:0; or for a better practice use an id if is a one element style.

```
<h3 id="title" > my title <h3>
```

And in your stylesheet something like

```
#title {
       padding:0;
      }
```

Or you can use a class if you will use the same style in different elements for example if you want to use it in a p tag.

```
<h3 class="custom"> My title </h3>
<p class="custom"> My paragraph </p>
```

And in your stylesheet something like

```
.custom {
   padding:0;
  }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In your html:

```
<h3 id="unique">
```

Stylesheet:

```
  #unique{
   padding:0px;
   color:grey;
                  }
```

I hope, It helps you..

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the element a class and apply the padding to it in your css file or tag, for exmaple:

```
<div class="col-12">
   <h3 class="section-title">WAIVER</h3>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
     <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   </div
   <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
     <p>lorem ipsum</p>
   </div
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section-padding {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:grey;
    padding: 0;
}
```